# Why standard picklsit is not part of dependent fields?

Tags: standard-objects, dependent-picklist

please answer my question as iam in a bit confusion. thanks i advance..I have tried i many websites why  A Standard picklist is not a dependent picklist?

Comment: you might illustrate your question with an example to make it clearer to the reader as to what exactly the issue is that you are having.

Comment: ravi you're going to need to provide more information here, why should standard picklists be dependent? Are you talking about a specific field?

Answer (score 1):

According to the help docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=en_US), it is a picklist limitation:

> **Picklist limitations**
>
> Custom picklist fields can be either controlling or dependent fields.
>
> Standard picklist fields can be controlling fields but not dependent
>   fields.
>
> The maximum number of values allowed in a controlling field is 300. In
>   addition, if a field is both a controlling field and dependent
>   picklist, it can't contain more than 300 values.
>
> Before defining a dependency, make sure your picklist has at least one
>   value; standard fields like Product Family do not contain any values
>   until you add them.
>
> If a standard controlling field relies on functionality that your
>   organization decides to disable, the dependency rules for the picklist
>   will go away. For example, if your organization disables the
>   Self-Service portal and the Closed by Self-Service User is a
>   controlling field, its dependent picklist will display all available
>   values.
>
> The following fields are not available as controlling fields:
>
> **Activity Fields**
>
> Call Type
>
> Create recurring series of events
>
> Show Time As
>
> Subject
>
> Task
>
> Type
>
> **Contact Fields**
>
> Salutation
>
> Contact Currency
>
> **Custom Object Fields**
>
> Currency
>
> **Lead Fields**
>
> Converted
>
> Unread By Owner